# Google Cloud Service Account & Calendar

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

Does anyone know how to enable the option for "Make changes & Manage sharing"? I have enabled a service account and the google cal api.

https://pasteboard.co/m0QpAWnmT6ZR.png

I keep getting this error on my WordPress site.

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
(
[errors] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[domain] => calendar
[reason] => requiredAccessLevel
[message] => You need to have writer access to this calendar.
)

)

[code] => 403
[message] => You need to have writer access to this calendar.
)

)
```

Comment: Where is hosted your wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **External sharing options for primary calendars** in the **Sharing settings** of Google Calendar in Google Admin page.

To change that

1. Go to *admin.google.com*.
2. Log in the admin credentials.
3. Click the  Main Menu (hamburger menu) in the upper left side of your screen.
4. Select **Apps** -> **Google Workspace** -> **Calendar**
5. Click **Sharing settings**
6. Change the value of **External sharing options for primary calendars** to **Share all information, and allow managing of calendars**
7. Click Save.

It should look something like this.

[image]

***Note**: Changes may take up to 24 hours to propagate to all users.*

### Example:

External sharing options for primary calendars is set to **Only free/busy information (hide event details):**

[image]

External sharing options for primary calendars is set to **Share all information, and allow managing of calendars:**

[image]

### Reference

- [Set Calendar visibility & sharing options](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en)